"Error: Element type is invalid" with AWS Amplify's `signOut` and `Hub` Imports
I've recently updated my project to use the latest version of AWS Amplify and followed the new documentation guidelines for importing modules. However, I'm facing a recurring issue when trying to import signOut from the AWS Amplify Auth module, as well as encountering similar issues with the Hub module. The specific error message I encounter is as follows:

Code used straight from AWS Amplify's site:
import { signOut } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

async function handleSignOut() {
  try {
    await signOut({ global: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error signing out: ', error);
  }
}

I know this code is the issue, as when I remove the import and refresh the page, the error is removed. I found this experience too with Hub. Same issue.
